# Object Constraint - Object won't make a 360º rotation

Tags: modeling, constraints

What I'm doing wrong here? Why is the gear like reseting its rotation?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iMZq.jpg (Gif too heavy to upload here)

[image: g ro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because that's how the Transformation constraint works w/r/t to rotation.

From the Blender Manual:

> When using the rotation transform properties of the target as input, whatever the real values are, the constraint will always “take them back” into the (-180 to 180) range. E.g. if the target has a rotation of 420 degrees around its X axis, the values used as X input by the constraint will be:
>
> ((420+180)modulo360)−180=60−...
>
> This is why this constraint is not really suited for gears!

You can use rigid body simulation to animate these properly, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.